# Android Flavors - Separate drawable directory for each app?

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Is it possible to have the same codebase but a different drawable directory for each app?

Basically i want to have the same app multiple times, just rebranded, so everything can be identical except for the images in the drawable folders.

Any ideas?

I want my directory structure to look like this:

```
manifest
java
assets
res
   anim
   animator
   drawables
     main
        drawable
           logo.png
           background.png
           xxx.png
           yyy.png
     flavor1
        drawable
           logo.png
           background.png
     flavor2
        drawable
           logo.png
           background.png
   layout
   menu
   values
   xml
```

Comment: You might wish to consider explaining in greater detail what directory structure you are seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare - i have updated my question to show the folder structure i'm trying to emulate :)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Gradle is pretty flexible, so I can't completely rule it out.

Comment: No worries, i'll keep searching and if i figure it out i'll update it on here. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @CommonsWare - i've got it working a different way, my res folder now contains 'main', 'flavorone' and 'flavortwo' folders.  The main res folder has all the drawables, layouts, values, xml files etc.  In flavorone and flavortwo i override whatever i need to from the main res folder, so they only hold what they need to override from the main res folder, nothing else.  It works well :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep. This is one of the Main features of android flavors. All you need to do is create a new folder at the same level as your "main" directory and name it as the desired favor.
In this new folder you need to copy the structure and use the same name for the drawables you want to override. Gradle will pick up these resources first if present but will take any not present from the Main folder by default.

Comment: Ahhh right so basically only put in the flavor what i'm going to override.  So if i'm going to just override the logo then only add a drawable folder  and logo.png to that flavor?

Comment: Yup, you got it, just remember to keep the structure. To clarify a drawable placed in main/res/drawable/logo.xml is going to be replaced by a logo placed in {brand_name}/res/drawable/logo.xml

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help.  I was trying to go for a different approach (see my edited answer for folder structure) but your approach will work perfectly for what i need.  Thanks Pato94.  I'm loving these Flavors!

Comment: Can i copy all files in the main folder to the flavor1 for gradle not go to main folder again such as if i have in main manifest , java, and res folder. I copy it to flavor 1